# Table with update of classes and variables based on which column and row line is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following table:

```
<table class="ui celled table unstackable" id="tblHits">
   <tbody>
       <tr class="five" width="50px" height="50px">
         <td class="Result addNone" id="r01">01</td>
         <td class="Result addNone" id="r02">02</td>
         <td class="Result addNone" id="r03">03</td>
         <td class="Result addNone" id="r04">04</td>
         <td class="Result addNone" id="r05">05</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="five" width="50px" height="50px">
           <td class="Diameter add40" id="d01">Target Size</td>
           <td class="Diameter add40" id="d02">Target Size</td>
           <td class="Diameter add40" id="d03">Target Size</td>
           <td class="Diameter add40" id="d04">Target Size</td>
           <td class="Diameter add40" id="d05">Target Size</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="five" width="60px" height="60px">
           <td class="Stance addStance" id="s01"></td>
           <td class="Stance addStance" id="s02"></td>
           <td class="Stance addStance" id="s03"></td>
           <td class="Stance addStance" id="s04"></td>
           <td class="Stance addStance" id="s05"></td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

I also have some logic to change the stance columns classes to display different pictures defined as follows:

```
$('#tblHits').on('click', function (evt) {
    var $td = $(evt.target);
    if (!$td.is('.Stance')) return;
    if ($td.hasClass('addStance')) {
        $td.removeClass('addStance').addClass('addStanding');
        TargetsStanding += 1;
        TargetsStanceND -= 1;
        $('#drpTargetNo').prop('disabled', true);
    } else
        if ($td.hasClass('addStanding')) {
            $td.removeClass('addStanding').addClass('addKneeling');
            TargetsStanding -= 1;
            TargetsKneeling += 1;
        } else
            if ($td.hasClass('addKneeling')) {
                $td.removeClass('addKneeling').addClass('addProne');
                TargetsKneeling -= 1;
                TargetsProne += 1;
            } else
                if ($td.hasClass('addProne')) {
                    $td.removeClass('addProne').addClass('addStance');
                    TargetsProne -= 1;
                    TargetsStanceND += 1;
                }
});

$('#tblHits').on('click', function (evt) {
    var $td = $(evt.target);
    if (!$td.is('.Result')) return;

    if ($td.hasClass('addNone')) {
        $td.removeClass('addNone').addClass('addHit');
        Score += 1;
        TargetsLeft -= 1;
        TargetsHit += 1;
        $('#txtTargetsLeft').val(TargetsLeft);
        $('.resultHits').html(Score);
        $('.resultTotal').html(parseInt(Score) + parseInt(TargetsMissed));
        $('#drpTargetNo').prop('disabled', true);
    } else
        if ($td.hasClass('addHit')) {
            $td.removeClass('addHit').addClass('addMiss');
            Score -= 1;
            TargetsHit -= 1;
            TargetsMissed += 1;
            $('.resultHits').html(Score);
            $('.resultMisses').html(TargetsMissed);
            $('.resultTotal').html(parseInt(Score) + parseInt(TargetsMissed));
        } else
            if ($td.hasClass('addMiss')) {
                $td.removeClass('addMiss').addClass('addNone');

                TargetsLeft += 1;
                TargetsMissed -= 1;
                $('.resultMisses').html(TargetsMissed);
                $('.resultTotal').html(parseInt(Score) + parseInt(TargetsMissed));
                $('#txtTargetsLeft').val(TargetsLeft);
            }
});
```

So what i want, is that when we click either the result table line columns or the stance row column, that i want to check if the result has class 'addHit' or 'addMiss' and update some variabled so i can count numbers for both hits and misses.

The jquery code i am trying to figure out is from the stance point of view:

```
$('.Stance').on('click', function (e) {
   var hits = 0;
   var misses = 0;
   // Alert($('.Result').attr($(this).attr('id')));
   $('.Result').html($(this).attr('id'));
   if ($('.Result').attr($(this).attr('id')).hasClass('addHit')) {
      hits +=1;
   }
   else if($('.Result').attr($(this).attr('id')).hasClass('addMiss')) {
          misses +=1;
        }
        else{
              hits-=1;
              misses-=0;
            }
           alert(hits + "were hit and " + misses + "were missed");
            });
```

Any clues on how i can count values on the hits either if you hit the result row columns or the stance row columns concerning this code? Im ean, if i click in the s01 column, i want to check if the r01 has the class addHit. all ids with 01 on the rows with classes result, stance and diameter, should be connected together somehow. I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: `id` attributes *must* be unique within the DOM.

Comment: OK thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the table with unique id attributes. I still have trouble figuring this out though.

Comment: This if - `if ($('.Result').attr($(this).attr('id')).hasClass('addHit'))` what is that supposed to do?

Comment: It's checking if the result column's attribute id based on the id of the selected row from .Stance class has the class 'addHit' set. I see now that this will not work, since i have updated the ids to be unique and will no longer match.... Based on the rows the columns in each of the 3 rows are in a way together as an unit. meaning if i click on the stance column, i want to check that resultcolumn if it has a class set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this was way to complicated way doing this. so i created another function instead which is loaded when we click the button statistics and looks as follows:

```
function checkStatistics() {
    TargetsStandingHit = 0;
    TargetsKneelingHit = 0;
    TargetsProneHit = 0;
    TargetsStanceHit = 0;
    TargetsHit10mm = 0;
    TargetsHit15mm = 0;
    TargetsHit25mm = 0;
    TargetsHit30mm = 0;
    TargetsHit40mm = 0;
    TargetsDiameterHit = 0;
    $('.Result').each(function () {
        //Hide it
        var value = $('#drpTargetNo').val();
        //alert(value);
        if ($(this).html() <= value) {
            splitresult = 'r' + $(this).html()
            splitvalue = 's' + $(this).html()
            splitvalue2 = 'd' + $(this).html()
            //alert($('.Stance').attr('id') = 's'+splitvalue);
            if ($("[id='" + splitresult + "']").hasClass('addHit')) {
                if ($("[id='" + splitvalue + "']").hasClass('addStanding')) {
                    //alert($("[id='" + splitvalue + "']").attr('id')); 
                    TargetsStandingHit += 1;
                } else
                    if ($("[id='" + splitvalue + "']").hasClass('addKneeling')) {
                        TargetsKneelingHit += 1;

                    } else
                        if ($("[id='" + splitvalue + "']").hasClass('addProne')) {
                            TargetsProneHit += 1;
                        }
                        else
                            if ($("[id='" + splitvalue + "']").hasClass('addStance')) {
                                TargetsStanceHit += 1;
                            }
                if ($("[id='" + splitvalue2 + "']").html() == '10mm') {
                    //alert($("[id='" + splitvalue + "']").attr('id')); 
                    TargetsHit10mm += 1;
                } else
                    if ($("[id='" + splitvalue2 + "']").html() == '15mm') {
                        TargetsHit15mm += 1;

                    } else
                        if ($("[id='" + splitvalue2 + "']").html() == '25mm') {
                            TargetsHit25mm += 1;
                        }
                        else
                            if ($("[id='" + splitvalue2 + "']").html() == '30mm') {
                                TargetsHit30mm += 1;
                            }
                            else
                                if ($("[id='" + splitvalue2 + "']").html() == '40mm') {
                                    TargetsHit40mm += 1;
                                }
                                else
                                    if ($("[id='" + splitvalue2 + "']").html() == 'Target Size') {
                                        TargetsDiameterHit += 1;
                                    }
            }
        }
    });

}
```